# Javascript: gradually adding to string in each iteration?

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this that is split up:

```
var tokens = "first>second>third>last".split(">");
```

What I would like in each iteration is for it to return

```
Iteration 0: "last"
Iteration 1: "third>last"
Iteration 2: "second>third>last"
Iteration 3: "first>second>third>last"
```

I am thinking of using decrementing index for loop.... but is there a more efficient approach ?

```
for (int w = tokens.length-1; w == 0; w--)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var tokens = "first>second>third>last".split(">");

var out = []

while(tokens.length) {
   out.unshift(tokens.pop());
   console.log(out.join('>'))
}
```

Comment: -1. This stack based approach is neat but incorrect.  It reverses the order of the tokens, which the OP did not ask for.  Use of the `unshift()` method of the array type should do what you want, but may not work in some versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: @fmark, thanks, I didn't read carefully enough, but it was pretty simple to fix.

Comment: @mikerobi Sorry to be a pedant, but your fixed version is still incorrect.  Now it produces output from the wrong "end" of the token list.  You should be reversing the `out` variable prior to printing it, not the input `tokens`.

Comment: @fmark, thats what I get for posting code without testing it, but I finally corrected it. Funny thing is, my wrong answer was accepted.

Comment: @mikerobi, an accepted answer is a great incentive to get people fix it too.

Answer (score 0):

OTOH this is the simplest aproach

```
var tokens = "first>second>third>last".split(">");

text = ''
for (w = tokens.length-1; w >= 0; w--)
{
    if(text != ''){
        text = tokens[w] + '>'+text;
    }else{
        text = tokens[w]
    }

    console.log(text);
}
```

Comment: You could avoid the use of an if statement by using the `join()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
var tokens = "first>second>third>last".split(">"); 

for (var w = 0; w < tokens.length; w++)
{
  var substr = tokens.slice(tokens.length - 1 - w, tokens.length).join(">");
  console.log("Iteration " + w + ": " + substr)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use join to reverse the original split. I'm not sure about efficiency but it's quite legible:

```
var tokens = 'first>second>third>last'.split('>');

for (var i = tokens.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    var subset = tokens.slice(i).join('>');
    console.log(subset);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var tokens = "first>second>third>last".split(">");
var text = [];
for (var i = tokens.length; --i >= 0;) {
    text.unshift(tokens[i]);
    var str = text.join(">");
    alert(str); // replace this with whatever you want to do with str
}
```

Should do the trick.